# Lookup in arrayList

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, data-structures

I am trying to do a lookup for a corresponding value for an entry item  in an arraylist (alphanumeric value and its hashcode).

The use of hashmap was dropped to allow duplication of objects(keys).

`ArrayList<Object[]> pNArrayList = new ArrayList<Object[]>();` contains

```
[101E2571G103, -1162488899]
[101E2571G103, -1162488899]
[116E3139P001, -1561106156]
[314B7159G003, -1344220682]
[117E3640G025, -1595019143]
[117E3640G025, -1595019143]
```

For an input, `inputID` of type **long**

```
for(int i=0; i< pNHashArrayList.size();i++) {
            if(pNArrayList.get(i)[1].equals(inputID)){
                System.out.println(pNArrayList.get(i)[0]);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(pNArrayList.get(i)[0] + " and "+ pNArrayList.get(i)[1] +" No Match Found");
            }
        }
```

The `else` and `SysOut`statement thereafter were included only to cross validate.

output:

```
 101E2571G103 and -1162488899 No Match Found
 101E2571G103 and -1162488899 No Match Found
 116E3139P001 and -1561106156 No Match Found
 314B7159G003 and -1344220682 No Match Found
 117E3640G025 and -1595019143 No Match Found
 117E3640G025 and -1595019143 No Match Found
```

I think, the problem might be in the `pNArrayList.get(i)[1].equals(inputID)`?. Need some suggestions on this.

Also, my actual dataset will have around 10,000 entires, would the lookup by looping have problem with runtime computations?

Comment: Also print the value of `inputID` in Sysout to further debug why is not equal to `pNArrayList.get(i)[1]`.

Comment: @Mahendra `inputID` was `-1595019143` which actually exists in the ArrayList. This is where I fail to understand the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how you build your data structure.  However, a better design is to have a `Map<Long, List<Object>>` with the Long `inputID` as key, and the value can be a List of `Object`s that all belong to the same ID.  This way you support multiple values for the same key and the lookup is O(1)

regarding the equals, it is `Object`'s equals that is invoked, rather than `Long` one.  The proposed data structure should solve this problem as well.

Comment: Is there a way to handle the problem with the existing data structure?

Answer (score 0):

Good approach is suggested by @sharonbn, but you can try this to run your existing code :

```
        if( ((Long)pNArrayList.get(i)[1]) == inputID){
            System.out.println(pNArrayList.get(i)[0]);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(pNArrayList.get(i)[0] + " and "+ pNArrayList.get(i)[1] +" No Match Found");
        }
    }
```

Comment: What worked for me was to add empty string to  `if (pNArrayList.get(i)[1].equals(""+inputID))`

Comment: This is only possible in case you have added _inputID_ as String in Object[]. But as you mentioned "_For an input, inputID of type long_", then you are checking equality of Long object with a String object.